# how to set different values to same editext in different activity in android

Tags: android

I am trying to send the values for the same edittext in another activity. But I am getting this error. Please do help me.

I am getting the values as 0.0 when I am trying to give values with if and else-if statements,but I am getting the correct values when I am going with only one if statement.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int id = item.getItemId();
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.done:
Intent obj = new Intent(MainActivity5.this, MainActivity10.class);
if (Float.parseFloat(ins3.getText().toString()) > 0 && Float.parseFloat(ins6.getText().toString())>0) {


float grain = (float) (2.455 * (Float.parseFloat(ins3.getText().toString())) - 14.071);

obj.putExtra("key", grain);
} else if (Float.parseFloat(ins4.getText().toString()) > 0 && Float.parseFloat(ins6.getText().toString())>0 &&(ins3.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
float grain = (float) (1.949 * (Float.parseFloat(ins4.getText().toString())) -12.799);
}
obj.putExtra("key6", grain);
}
```

Another Activity:

```
Intent i=getIntent();
Float value=i.getFloatExtra("key", 0);
Float value6=i.getFloatExtra("key6", 0);
ins.setText(String.valueOf(value));
ins.setText(String.valueOf(value6));
```

Comment: First thing I see is you have a ´case´ statement without any ´switch´

Comment: I have kept switch even though i am not able to get it please do help me

Comment: What I would do from here would be to add Log.d(TAG, item.getItemId()+" = "+R.id.done); right after your line with the switch statement. If the values match, then move on from there, if not then figure out why. Essentially I'm just trying to make sure your Switch and Case is even executing properly, because the default value you assign the 'value' and 'value6' variables is 0.0, and that's what you're getting, which suggests that the Case statement is not executing properly.

Comment: @ArmaAK I am getting correct values when I am setting the 'value' only in the second activity.But when I am setting the same edittext with second value 'value6' for different condition Then I am getting 0.0

Comment: But you're sure the switch and case is executing?

Comment: Yeah since I have got output with one if statement

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity, you need to actually retrieve the extras, not just the intent.Do:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
float value = extras.getFloat("key",0);
float value6 = extras.getFloat("key6",0);
ins.setText(String.valueOf(value));
ins.setText(String.valueOf(value6));
```

Comment: There is no difference between what you've written and what OP is using. (In terms of retrieving values)